# Page Variant Not showing content and preview not working

Tags: php, drupal-6, pass-by-reference

I've copied a drupal6 site from a production server onto a dev server and have started trying to get it up and running and most of it runs ok except page variant.

On the live site the page variant shows on, on the dev site I can select the "Content" menu item and see all content that is supposed to be showing in the appropriate area however when It try to view on the front end on dev it shows the page wrapper but the main content area is blank.

When I click on the "Preview" menu item in the page variant admin the page doesn't display, however selecting this on the live server shows it fine.

It feels like a permissions / setting issue to me but so far I've not been able to figure it out.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was a "Call-time pass-by-reference" issue and was caused by different PHP versions on live & dev.  PHP 5.3 seems to allow the call allowed this call but gave a deprecation warning but the new dev server is on an updated version of PHP which doesn't allow this anymore (although it wasn't giving any errors either) so I had to make the following change (and will likely have several similar ones to do before I'm finished)

Had to update a function template_preprocess_panels_pane in in panels.module from

```
function template_preprocess_panels_pane($vars)
```

to

```
function template_preprocess_panels_pane(&$vars) {
```

as described in comment 21 on https://drupal.org/comment/6820396#comment-6820396

These was also a suggestion that you could update a php.ini value to allow call-time pass by  reference (change allow_call_time_pass_reference = Off to allow_call_time_pass_reference = On in php.ini) but updating the code where necessary feels a better way to go.